# SoundCloud API for Android - Google+ - SignIn not working

Tags: android, google-plus, soundcloud, google-signin

I am using the SoundCloud API in my application and I wish to add support for Google + Sign in. Facebook and email sign in works well.

I followed the steps from [https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference][1] and used an WebView to display the connect URL. For FB login I was sent to the redirect_uri specified by me but for Google+ this does not happen and I am returned to a blank page.

Should I add any Google+ special settings?

[UPDATE]
 And the URL from the webview is:

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?zt=ChRrSW5rQzhRb0FCN2FXYmN2OUU3UBIfSWgtRWd0QlJVcThSWUZacjk1dXlndlZSZ0syTWx3SQ%E2%88%99APsBz4gAAAAAVO80WV2bOdZGqYKRwpTOIlAweRpfRufL&from_login=1&hl=ro&as=-3b89b18baa28338a

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Soundcloud API mobile OAUTH login using Google+ isn't working on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24877284/soundcloud-api-mobile-oauth-login-using-google-isnt-working-on-android)

Answer (score 0):

this is what I am doing for `SoundCloud` `login`

```
    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web.loadUrl(url+"&client_id="+CLIENT_ID+"&redirect_uri=http://localhost&response_type=token&scope=non-expiring&display=popup");
    web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
          boolean authComplete = false;
          @Override
          public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon){
           super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
           progress_dialog.show_message("Connecting SoundCloud");
           progress_dialog.show_dialog();
          }
       String authCode="";
          @Override
          public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
              super.onPageFinished(view, url);
              progress_dialog.Cancel_dialog();
              Log.i("URLLLL", url);
              if (url.contains("access_token=") && authComplete != true) {
                  for(int t=32;t<url.length();t++){
                      if(!(url.charAt(t) == '&'))
                      authCode = authCode+url.charAt(t);
                      else
                      break;
                  }
                  Log.i("CODE true", "CODE : " + authCode);
                  authComplete = true;
                  SharedPreferences.Editor edit = pref.edit();
                  edit.putString("SoundCloud_Code", authCode);
                  edit.putInt("SoundCloud_signinflag", 1);
                  edit.commit();
                  sign_in_flag = 1;
                  auth_dialog.dismiss();
                  new getprofile().execute();
              }else if(url.contains("error=access_denied")){
                  Log.i("CODE false", "ACCESS_DENIED_HERE");
                  authComplete = true;
                  auth_dialog.dismiss();
              }
          }
      });
    auth_dialog.show();
```

and it is just working perfect.

Please try this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This works for Facebook (but FB worked before also) but for Google + I still receive a blank screen . I click Google+ button. I introduce user and pass. I click sign in and then I get the blank screen and this are the URL's from the webview: (see update)

Answer (score 0):

This questions has been answered here: [Soundcloud API mobile OAUTH login using Google+ isn't working on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24877284/soundcloud-api-mobile-oauth-login-using-google-isnt-working-on-android/38515842#38515842)

I created a github project [here](https://github.com/bulwinkel/SoundCloudLogin) which has a fully working implementation.